# How to add "variable.html" in include function of Django instead of hard coding the template name?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to render different HTML templates for each product detail view. I used this url pattern

```
path('product-detail/<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
```

Here is the view for product detail view

```
class ProductDetailView(View):
def get(self, request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render (request, 'esell/productdetail.html', {'product':product})
```

Here is the detail template

```
<h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
 <hr>
 <p>Product Description: {{ product.description }}</p>
```

I want different detail templates to show for different product clicking on the product url. I tried to name the different html templates based one their id name like this "1.html" and tried to add include function to render different templates based on their id name like this

```
{% include '{{product.id}}.html' %}
```

But it's not working. Is there any way to add variable like that in include or other way to complete this task?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an  `{%if some_variable %}` and then `{%include 'xxx.html'%}`